# Production and development mode CSS mismatch

Tags: css, vue.js, webpack, production

I am using `Vuetify` framework with custom CSS added to it. My project is a webpack template. In development mode, my custom CSS changes apply to the HTML elements, but in Production mode, those changes are not displayed. What would I need to do to have my custom CSS apply in Production mode?

I have already tried re-building the project. The project is a Maven project, running with SpringBoot.

```
<template>
<div>
    <div>
        <v-expansion-panel>
            <v-expansion-panel-content v-for="(item,i) in dashboardTitles" :key="i">
                <div slot="header">
                    <div class="title-header">
                        {{item.title}}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </v-expansion-panel-content>
        </v-expansion-panel>
    </div>
</div>
</template>
<style>
.v-expansion-panel__header {
    background-color: #005f81;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    color: white;
    min-height: 20px;
    max-height: 30px;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.title-header {
    margin-left: 30px;
}

.theme--light.v-expansion-panel .v-expansion-panel__container .v-expansion-panel__header .v-expansion-panel__header__icon .v-icon,
.v-expansion-panel__container--active > .v-expansion-panel__header .v-expansion-panel__header__icon .v-icon {
    color: white;
}

.v-expansion-panel__header__icon {
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    outline: none;
}
</style>
```

`.v-expansion-panel__header` class should make the panels slimmer and the text smaller, while `.theme--light.v-expansion-panel .v-expansion-panel__container .v-expansion-panel__header .v-expansion-panel__header__icon .v-icon` and `.v-expansion-panel__container--active > .v-expansion-panel__header .v-expansion-panel__header__icon .v-icon` should make the arrow that comes with the framework component white. Funnily enough, `.v-expansion-panel__header__icon` works as intended, moving the arrow to the right rather than to the left

Comment: Can you check in your devtools whether this is an issue of CSS order? Maybe your values get overwritten by the defaults. This could be solved with `!important` (please don't :D ) or maybe even scoped styles work (which would simply be adding a `scoped` attribute to your style tag.

Comment: @HerrSiering I have tried using scoped and all it does is remove ALL the CSS from the component, including `Vuetify` CSS. Also !important does not work, values still get overwritten.

Comment: If they get overwritten, at least they are there :) You can bump up the CSS specificity for them, either by chaining the same class (e.g. `.title-header.title-header.title-header` – twice, thrice, more often) or by prepending them with `body #app .title-header` (where `#app` is my guess of your app container) so they don't get overwritten but "win" the specificity battle :)

Comment: @HerrSiering I will give that a go and see if it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to solve the issue by prepending the CSS styles I have added to the `Vuetify` CSS classes and also adding `!important` to make sure they get applied.